# Ruby: return the first character from string if it matches and if there is no match then return nil?

Tags: ruby

is there a built in way to get first match or nil for a character from string.

i can get a first character like this

```
'word'.match('o').to_s
```

but if there is no match it gives `""` not nil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`String#[match_str]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> If a `match_str` is given, that string is returned if it occurs in the string.
>
> Returns `nil` if (...) the match string cannot be found.

```
'word'['o'] #=> 'o'
'word'['q'] #=> nil
```

The `[]` method is very versatile, you can also pass a regular expression or indices in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in such way:

```
'word'.scan('o').first #=> "o"

'word'.scan('e').first #=> nil
```

Comment: why i didn't think of this

Answer (score 1):

```
'word'.match(?o)[0] rescue nil
#=> "o"

'word'.match(?q)[0] rescue nil
#=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'word'.match(/(o)/) && $1
#⇒ "o"
'word'.match(/(s)/) && $1
#⇒ nil
```